# move laravel project from live to local

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. I have a live project done by my colleague. I need to make some changes in the project. How can I move this project from live to local. I just downloaded the project and save to my localhost but it is not working. What are the changes need to setup this on local server

Comment: you getting any error ?

Comment: You'll find everything you need to know right [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation).

Comment: Have you run command `composer update` OR `composer install`?

Comment: did you migrate database?

Comment: Can you tell us what issues you're having i.e. what errors you're getting, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Yogendrasinh composer already installed

Comment: @geeth So you have vendor folder in your locally moved project? Also in your database have you migrate your migration files using `php artisan migrate`? What error you are getting when you run your project in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, that approach should be fine as long as you treat your local copy as a fresh Laravel installation.  In other words, you'll probably need to update your local .env file with your database connections and app properties (or by adjusting appropriate files in the config directory) and then open a command prompt and navigate to your local copy and run `run npm install`, `composer install`, `php artisan migrate` and `npm run dev`.

This will install any missing dependencies that your app requires, setup your local database and recompile local assets like css and javascript.  Once that is successful, you should be able to run `php artisan serve` and browser to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to confirm everything is up and running.